# Htaccess Rule Not Working To Disallow an Area of My Website

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So I have been struggling with this website for a few days now. I am trying to optimise the website from a SEO viewpoint and for that reason we need to rewrite several URLs on the website since they are hard coded with "/?breadcrumb" in the URL.

We needed a 301 rewrite rule that would rewrite everything on the website that contained a "?" in the URL to the last forward slash. This was working fine until we noticed it was affecting CSS and JavaScript files. We then added a new rule to prevent this rule from being applied to the CSS and JavaScript files. Everything was then working fine until we noticed that the store search was not working and products would not load in the administrator back end.

Here are the rules we have so far:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .(css|js)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]


RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .+
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1? [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+?[^/])$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^product/([^/]+)/?$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

We are struggling as we need to rewrite any URL that contains the "?" in the URL to the last forward slash however we need to prevent this rule from applying to "/store/search/*" and "/administratorlogin/*". I also want to add that "/administratorlogin/*" is on https if this makes a difference.

I have read online and have tried the RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/store/search/?$ however this dosen't work.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Whoa, whoa, whoa. What is your starting point (the desired SEO format URI coming in from visitors, etc.), and what do you need to end up with (dynamic non-SEO format that the server and scripting language can handle)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(store/search|administratorlogin) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(css|js)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .+
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1/? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+?[^/])$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^product/([^/]+)/?$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```